# jQuery: using ".each" for a select's options by $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know there are a lot of similar questions but I still could not find one about my exact problem. I haven't got the `selector` of my `<select>`; I am iterating form fields and so i only got access to my `select` by using `$(this)`.

how can I iterate this `select`'s options by using `jQuery`'s '.each' function?

i tried to chain it, but this doesn't work:

```
$(this).$('option').each(function(){
    if (this.value == val) {
    // do something
    }
});
```

**note:** `$(this)` is my `select` not my `form`.

Comment: And what about: `$(this).find('option:selected').doSomething().orWhatever();`. You really would have better to explain what you are looking for instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `this` is a reference to the `select` element you also have access to its `.options` property which you can wrap in a `jQuery` object:

```
$( this.options ).each( function(i, option){
    if (this.value == val) {
    // do something
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x57d8msL/

Comment: wow, this is a nice solution as well. so i assume `this.options` is native javascript? since this answer doesn't need jQuery's `find()` function, i guess it should perform better - or am I wrong?

Comment: It may be marginally faster, in the order of nanoseconds probably, so don't consider it an optimization - but yes, `select.options` is a native way to access the list of options of a select element.

Comment: great, thank you! i am sorry for Bhushan Kawadkar, but i liked your answer better. it uses very simple native javascript which made me learn something new.

Answer (score 3):

Try this : you can use `.find()` to get `option` under select.

Note: - `this.value` refers to current option value inside loop.

```
$(this).find('option').each(function(){
    if (this.value == val) {
    // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: tyvm, this seems to work. i knew there must be a simple way, just could not **find** it myself :)

Comment: but i also like pawel's answer since it doesn't need to use `find()` at all - hard decision which answer to accept.

Comment: Yeah that one is pretty good, he has used attribute to get `option` using `$(this.options)` where `this` refers to `select`.

Comment: This is also perfectly correct answer, I'd add one more way to do this: `$('option', this).each()`, which utilizes the fact that the second argument to jQuery is a context within which the search is performed.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.each($('select'), function (key, val){
    console.log($(val));
});
```